# How to generate isoString from a string with knowing format

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, momentjs

I have the following string

```
let S1=: “2021-01-02 11:11:11”
```

I know the format : “YYYY-dd-MM hh:mm:ss”

How to generate isoString format from the string knowing the input format?

Eq.

```
let time = moment(S1)
```

=> in this case confuze the day with minte

I want a general solution because the format input will have different types.

Answer (score 3):

Your format is probably wrong: `yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss` is not a sensible format.

*Either* `mm` indicates "month" **or** it indicates "minutes", it can't do both (hint: it's the later: `mm` is minutes, `MM` is months).

You want `YYYY-dd-MM hh:mm:ss`.